# Is there a Twin City Liner sales office in Bratislava?

Tags: tickets, vienna, bratislava

I will be spending a few days in Vienna soon and I was planning a day trip to Bratislava on my arrival day. I have found train schedules and fares easily enough on [OBB's site](http://www.oebb.at/en/). I intend to travel to Bratislava by train from the main station, since I will be taking the IC/Railjet from the airport to Wien Hbf. I would like to take the [Twin City Liner](http://www.twincityliner.com/en) for the return trip to Vienna, however I can't find any information on purchasing tickets in Bratislava. The only information I can find mentions purchasing from the ticket office at Schwedenplatz.

So, can I purchase a one-way ticket for the Twin City Liner in Bratislava or is it only available at Schwedenplatz or online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Flora Tour](http://www.floratour.sk/ponuka/twin-city-liner-2/) (Twin City's Slovakian partner):

> **Selling points:** the tickets in the FLORA TOUR Headquarters on Kúpeľná Street (Bratislava), in the FLORA TOUR Office in the Passenger Port (Bratislava) or in FLORA TOUR Office at Schwedenplatz (Vienna). In the Kiosk under Nový most (Bratislava) it is possible to make a reservation.

The exact location of these selling points is available [on their website](http://www.floratour.sk/contact/).

Comment: Thank you for this. I completely missed the Flora Tour partner link on the Twin City Liner site.